# What does this construction mean?

Tags: grammar

With his sense of piercing irony, there went none of the typical friendliness of the Americans.

Comment: I don't know where you're getting all these "examples" from, but you should note that many of them don't seem to be things native speakers would normally say.

Answer (score 3):

It means

> *He had a sense of piercing irony, but it was not accompanied by the typical friendliness usually found in Americans.*

The original is much more succinct and would be understood by most native speakers. It uses the phrasal verb **[go with](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-with)**, meaning *accompany*, but the phrase is split in a way that makes it a bit more complex.

Comment: So this "there" is similar to this there" Above the table there hung a painting."

Comment: @username901345: You do not really need the word "there" in your exemplar sentence. In fact, I think it reads better without the "there," just as sentences beginning with "It" can usually be re-worded to get rid of the too-often used and indefinite "it." So, "With his sense of piercing irony went none of the typical friendliness of the Americans."

Comment: but this is from a native speaker.

Comment: No disrespect intended. We often work with multilingual members. The phrasing is a bit stilted, but generally understandable.